# IE 8 wont allow me setScr (mediaelement.js)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I am playing a video with mediaelement.js. Works fine but when I want to change the source of the video I get an error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setSrc'

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

code:

```
function playVideo(source) {

     var fileformat:string

     player.pause();

     if (Modernizr.video) {
         fileformat = ".mp4";
     } else {
       fileformat = ".flv";
     }

    var sources = [
        { src: 'media/'+ source + fileformat }
    ];

    player.setSrc(sources);
    player.load();
    player.play();

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: I guess you need something like `player.setSrc(""+sources[0].src+"");`